# дублированные значений переменной в потоке

Tags: c#, многопоточность, циклы

Здравствуйте, пишу от безысходности, написал программку, которая проверяет множество папок на сервере и ищет в них файл changelog.xml, при нахождении берет из него данные, сперва я написал линейный метод, который работает отлично, но медленно, в связи с этим переделал его под параллельное выполнение , выбрал значение 256 как стандартное для количества потоков.

При обработке ниже приведенного кода переменная link по непонятным для меня причинам имеет значения уже пройденных папок. Т.е. в итоге одна и та же папка проверяется несколько раз.

```
private void FinderParallelV3(int idT)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int gb = int.Parse(GB.Text), gb_ = int.Parse(GB_.Text), gs = int.Parse(GS.Text), gs_ = int.Parse(GS_.Text), v = int.Parse(V.Text), v_ = int.Parse(V_.Text);
        int step = 1, iCount = 0;
        string filePath = string.Format("./FOUND/listG{0}-{1}g{2}-{3}-v{4}-{5}-step{6}.txt", gb, gb_, gs, gs_, v, v_, step);
        Array arr = getDiapasonNew(v, v_);

        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath)) File.Create(filePath).Close();
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("Не удалось создать файл " + filePath); }


        int tCount = MIN_THREADS;
        threadsCombo.Invoke(new Action(() => { tCount = int.Parse(threadsCombo.SelectedItem.ToString()); }));

        if (tCount >= (v_ - v))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Данные настройки параметров поиска недопустимы." + Environment.NewLine + "Поиск не будет запущен.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }
        int a = gb;
        int b = gs;
        for (int t = 0; t <= tCount - 1; t++)
        {
            addThread(new Thread(() =>
            {
                int id = t;
                bool DoMain = true;
                int c = int.Parse(arr.GetValue(0, t - 1).ToString()), c_ = int.Parse(arr.GetValue(1, t - 1).ToString());
                string fw = null, model = null, type = null, link = null;
                int size = 0;
                int a_thread = a, b_thread = b;
                Task<bool> tryget = null;

                while (DoMain)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        iterCount.Invoke(new Action(() => { iterCount.Text = string.Format("Количество итераций : {0}", ++iCount); }));
                    }
                    catch { Console.WriteLine("ERROR ON 154"); }
                    for (int f = 1; f <= 4; f++)
                    {
                        link = string.Format("http://update.hicloud.com:8180/TDS/data/files/p3/s15/G{0}/g{1}/v{2}/f{3}/full/changelog.xml", a_thread, b_thread, c, f);
                        tryget = TryGetV3(link);
                        tryget.Wait();
                        if (tryget.Result)
                        {
                            tryget.Dispose();
                            fw = xmlGetModel(link);
                            size = xmlGetSize(link);

                            try
                            {
                                foreach (string s in readModels)
                                {
                                    if (fw.Contains(s))
                                    {
                                        model = s;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }


                                if (size > 1500000000) { type = "FULL"; } else { type = "OTA"; }
                                dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => { dataGridView1.Rows.Add(model, fw, type, link, "Download", a_thread, b_thread, c, f, size); }));
                                firmwareCount.Invoke(new Action(() => { firmwareCount.Text = string.Format("Найдено прошивок : {0}", dataGridView1.Rows.Count); }));


                            }
                            catch { Console.WriteLine("ERROR ON 188"); }


                        }
                        link = null;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        //dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() => { RemoveDuplicate(this.dataGridView1); }));
                        File.AppendAllText(filePath, string.Format(@"{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count].Value.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    catch { }

                    //V WHILE
                    ++c;
                    if (c < c_)
                        DoMain = true;
                    else
                        DoMain = false;


                    fw = null; model = null; type = null; link = null; size = 0; tryget = null;
                }
            }), t);
        }
    }
```

Посоветуйте какое нибудь решение данной проблемы, может и по оптимизации этой писанины.
Спасибо
P.S. Не судите строго, первая программка на C#

Comment: я бы добавил словарь и перед сканированием папки проверял в нем проверялась эта папка или нет, но нужно использовать потокобезопасную коллекцию. Или как вариант сначала составить список всех путей, а потом уже разбить на пакеты и и обрабатывать эти пакеты в разных потоках.

Comment: речь идет даже не опаре сотне вариантов, а о сотнях тысяч возможных расположений, getDiapasonNew в этом методе я разбиваю диапазон V на пакеты, т.е. равное количество V на каждый поток